# Sleepwatcher needs to be relaunch after every boot on Catalina

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, sleep-wake, launchd

I have a `.sleep` script that [sleepwatcher](https://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) launch everytime my MacBook Pro goes to sleep (by closing the lid).

On **Mojave**, everything worked fine. Now on **Catalina** (10.15.7), every time I boot:

- I have the message "can't open sleepwatcher because it's from an unidentified developer" popping up over and over again. I have to go to *System -> Security -> Open Anyway* in order to stop the message. (Thanks to @Allan, I managed to get *sleepwatcher* out of the quarantine flag).
- I have to relaunch the `.sleep` manually via the command line `/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --sleep ~/.sleep`  to get my script back running (on Mojave, the `.sleep` was automaticly loaded).

How can I make my Mac remember *sleepwatcher* & my `.sleep` setting like old times ?

Comment: I’m thinking that the quarantine flag is still set.  First, check it with the command `xattr appname.app`. If it comes back with `com.apple.quarantine`, the flag is set.  Remove it with the command `sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine Appname.app`

Comment: `xattr sleepwatcher.app` return `xattr: No such file: sleepwatcher.app`. *sleepwatcher* is connected to *homebrew*, could it be why there is no sleepwatcher.app ?

Comment: Make sure you're in the directory where sleepwatchet.app is located. But as far as Homebrew goes, I’ll have to research because I use MacPorts instead and my experience is limited there

Comment: I found *sleepwatcher* in `/usr/local/Cellar/sleepwatcher/2.2.1/sbin` and it was indeed in quarantine ! However, *sleepwatcher* still needs to be setup manually after rebooting... any idea why ?

Comment: So you remove it, then reboot and it reverts back to quarantine status?  If so, i don’t know why It’ll do that.  I will have to research more. Maybe it’s one of the sleepwatcher dependencies that’s also quarantined. Is there a way in homebrew to list an app’s dependencies?

Comment: No it is not in quarantine anymore, but I still need to relaunch it manually in order to get the .sleep script operational (and that was not the case in Mojave)